# Report Viewer for iPads

Tags: ipad, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have a reporting solution based on SSRS, but now, we have a requirement to support these reports in iPads as well...Is this possible with ReportViewer Contol? If not is there any other controls out there like Report Viewer Control that could meet the requirement...

What are the other options for me?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did some research for about this same issue a while back, could not find anything that would reproduced on safari the way reporter viewer with other browsers :-(  The nearest thing l could find was http://mobiweave.com/Products/BI.aspx.

This would only work with the SSRS site displaying SSRS reports.  Only posting this in case its of help to anyone else.  As that tool would have been the solution in a previous role. Where reports where accessed via intranet on Ipads.

Comment: I don't know if this is robust enough to count as an answer which is why I'm adding it as a comment. I found this [blog post](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/02/viewing-reporting-service-reports-ssrs.html).  The author shows examples of SketchMD app.

Answer (score 0):

It has been announced to be fixed in Q2 -12

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsofts-plan-for-bringing-its-bi-tools-to-ios-android-and-windows-8-devices/11005

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a third party iTunes app, such as [ReportPlus](http://pro.reportplus.com), which allows to display SSRS reports on the iPad, and use them for dashboard authoring.